# php script for comparing an string with other string

Tags: string, compare

i try to prevent users from duplicate post in my website  with php
to do this i check the title entered by user with title field in database and if record with this title found in database system show error message to user but some users change title with little character for example some user change character place like this:

main title: microsoft office lite(x86,x64)

```
change by user: microsoft office lite( x64,x86) 
change by user: microsoft office_lite( x86,x64)   
change by user: microsoft office_lite( x64,x86)  
change by user: microsoft office lite by rob( x64,x86)
```

is there anyway to check this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can eather use the php function `similar_text` to calculate the similarity (in percent) between two strings:

```
$str1 = 'microsoft office lite(x86,x64)';
$str2 = 'microsoft office lite( x64,x86)';
similar_text($str1, $str2, $percent);
if (percent < 95) {
    // accept it
} else {
    // error message
}
```

or (my recommanded way), use regex(http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) to strip your strings from spaces and other unwanted words (ex: by xxxx)

You can also use both methods to prevent small changes (like permutations).

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.similar-text.php